# Can we have "ssh "permissions are too open" error" moved to Server Fault?

Tags: discussion

The question *[ssh "permissions are too open" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open-error)* appears on Stack Overflow.

It is closed as off-topic.

Instead, the solution is not definitive. For example, if you work inside a VagrantBox with a Windows host, you can't do that change of permissions so simply, so the question needs more solutions.

Can the question be moved onto Server Fault?

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, except by staff in extremely special circumstances. I don't believe that question will qualify for "special circumstances."

Comment: Understood. Thnks Kendra.

Comment: It's not even a SF question, but a run-of-the-mill user issue, the permissions of the ssh private keys are "too open", these are supposed to be seen only by your users.

Comment: Or by a devops/sysadmin when creating/testing scripts for the users ;) - For example a sysadmin preparing a deployer machine run within a VirtalBox willing to connect to remote servers.

Comment: You don't need a cannon to kill a mosquito...

Answer (score 3):

I really don't see a reason for it to move.  [It exists on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/287734/169038) as well as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/290553/185768).  Both sites discuss this topic plenty already as it is, so I don't see any real benefit to adding yet another topic to the discussion.